# Where to load certificates for secured postgresql connections on Openshift?

Tags: postgresql, ssl, openshift

Following the resolution of this [issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1121727), I am trying to set-up secured connections from a node.js application to a postgresql 9.2 database in Openshift.

After connecting with `rhc ssh --app ligatures`, I am trying to find the `postgresql.conf` file using `find . -name 'postgresql.conf'`, but it returns nothing.

I can find two `/data` directories:

```
./app_root/data
./app_root/runtime/data
```

Both directories contain a `postgresql-9.2.tar.gz` file, but nothing else.

1. Where should I load/generate the certificate files required for
   [secured](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ssl-tcp.html) connections?
2. How can I verify the content of the `postgresql.conf` after setting environment variables such as `OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_SSL_ENABLED`?

**Update**

I performed the following test:

1. I have created proper certificates in the `./app_root/data` directory of my application, using the instructions available [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ssl-tcp.html).
2. I have set `OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_SSL_ENABLED=true`
3. I have tried to connect to the database using PgAdmin III.
4. I got a `Error connecting to the server: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required`

I have opened an [issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1191181) at RedHat bugzilla.

**Update II**

The solution to the issue opened above only works when the application is created as non-scalable. I have opened an extra [issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1194986) for scalable applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ssl-tcp.html) you're referring to `$PGDATA` which in case of OpenShift is `postgresql/data`. The problem you've also mentioned is related to that file location, if you enable SSL for postgresql, it checks for those cert files in `$PGDATA` if none is found server won't start, and that's the problem you described in the 2nd part of your question. I've fixed that by adding additional check which will turn SSL on only if `$PGDATA/server.crt` and `$PGDATA/server.key` exists, see [here](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/pull/6075). More info is in the [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1191181) you've created.

Comment: Solution works, but only for non-scalable applications. See my question for latest update.

Comment: As Ben stated [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1194986#c1): "When you have a scalable app, postgres (and any other db cartridge) gets its own gear, so the postgres data directory won't be on the head gear, which is where you are looking. You need to ssh into the postgres gear specifically. You can get the information about that gear by running: rhc app-show <appname> --gears.